# How to find list of files present in filepath in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have list of folder names. I want to check whether those files are present in a particular file path. If present I need to copy them to a different location; if not present I would like to print that.

Here is the script I wrote, but it's failing.

```
filename="$1"
while read -r line; do
  name="$line"
  if [ "ls -ltra /home/pandy/hotspot/ | grep $name"]; then
    echo "$name exists"
    cp /home/pandy/hotspot/$name /tmp
  else
    echo "$name not exists"
  fi
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: Is `file=((ls ...))` a typo? If not, what are you hoping to accomplish with that?

Comment: As mentioned in bio, I want to check list of files /folders are  present in particular file path, if present copy them into different location, if not present print on screen

Comment: But what are you hoping to accomplish with the syntax `file=(( ... ))`?

Comment: In that trying to print list of files present in particular path, may be wrong. May I know correct script to achieve my task ?

Comment: That should be `file=$(ls -ltra /home/hotspot/ | grep $name)`.

Comment: Here is how changed script  `filename="$1"
while read -r line; do
  name="$line"
  if [ "ls -ltra /home/pandy/hotspot/ | grep $name"]; then
    echo "$name exists"
  else
    echo "$name not exists"
  fi
done < "$filename"` Still its failing with error `2.sh: 4: [: missing ]
agent not exists
2.sh: 4: [: missing ]
test not exists
2.sh: 4: [: missing ]
pandy not exists`

Comment: `if [ "ls -ltra /home/pandy/hotspot/ | grep $name"]` is an error (`]` needs to be a separate argument, so must be preceded by a space), and `if [ "ls -ltra /home/pandy/hotspot/ | grep $name" ]` just checks if the specified string is non-empty (ie, it will always be true).  You just need `if ls -a /home/pandy/hotspot | grep -q "$name"; then ...`

Comment: But why are you using `grep` at all?  If you just want to know if the file exists, you can do `if [ -e /home/pandy/hotspot/"$name" ]; then ...`

Comment: But you don't even need to do the check!  Just execute `cp` and let it emit an error message if the file does not exist.